# Replace full stop between letters with hypen in sentance

Tags: regex, text, replace

Somehow some text pages I've been given seem to have a full stop where a hyphen should be.

For example, "Then it happened.first one foot.then the other.". As you can see there is a full-stop where a hyphen should be.

I figured out the Regex to 'find' `([a-z][.][a-z])` all the occurences but can't figure out the 'replace'.

When I tried, `[ - ]`, `[-]`, `[a-z][-][a-z]`, `[a-z][ - ][a-z]` and `[a-z][ ][-][ ][a-z]` it removes the last letter of the the precceding word and the first letter of the following one.

I'm using a text editor (TextPad).

How do I solve this?

Comment: You might match `.` surrounded by a word boundary instead?

Comment: If you use the pattern like yours, you will also remove `.` in abbreviations. E.g. `U.S.` -> `US.`

Comment: Which tool do you use to search and replace? `sed`, `perl`, or a text editor (which one)?

Comment: Luckily, all abbreviation are in capitals and I think I can use [a-z^A-Z] to remove finding capitals, although I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: @Socowi. Thanks for pointing this out. I changed the questions and added that I'm using a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have TextPad and cannot test my answer. From what I read, TextPad should support capture groups either via `\1` or `$1`. Try one of the following

Search `([a-z])\.([a-z])` and replace with `\1 - \2`
or
Search `([a-z])\.([a-z])` and replace with `$1 - $2`
or
Search `\([a-z]\)\.\([a-z]\)` and replace with `\1 - \2`.
or
Search `\([a-z]\)\.\([a-z]\)` and replace with `$1 - $2`.

Comment: Thanks @Socowi but this too, removes the last and first letters of the words before and after the '.' or splits all word into two letters and adds hypens between them.

Comment: What if the thing that comes after the period is a proper noun? `"Then it happened.Winnie the Pooh looked up."`

Comment: @SimonShine I just used OPs regex which OP deemed to be correct. This answer only provides the replace part.

Comment: @MartySmartyPants Strange. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/84663/652023) and [this cheat sheet](http://johnbokma.com/textpad/textpad-reference.pdf) one of them should work. However, comments on similar TextMate questions seem to suggest that different versions of TextMate have very different handling of capturing groups. Do you have settings for the search replace dialog you could change, for instance regex style?

Comment: @Socowi: You can use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid consuming the characters immediately before and after the matched period. Then you also don't need back-references.

Comment: @SimonShine True. Your answer is probably better than my answer. I cannot give you OP's acceptance, but at least my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider `[.](?=[a-z])`:

- It does avoid abbreviations assuming they're only uppercase.
- It does not handle "`Then it happened.Winnie the Pooh looked up.`" (The word after the hyphen is a proper noun.)
- It also does not handle "`Then it happened.G.W. Bush looked up.`" (The word after the hyphen is an abbreviation.)

To handle those cases, consider `(?<![A-Z])[.](?!\s|$)`:

- It says that the letter prior to the `.` should not be uppercase.
- It also says that there shouldn't be spaces or end-of-lines after it.

You can perform the replace with just `" - "`, since the regular expression only consumes the period. (The context is matched using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).)

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/3nV7gz/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
    var string = "Then it happened.first one foot.then the other."; 
    var result = string.replace(/[.]/g,'-');
```

Comment: `"Then it happened-first one foot-then the other-"` - there are two mistakes.